# AngularJS nested ng-repeat onclick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to create I dynamic ng-repeat, after populate it I want to add a click function on each repeat item and then on click I want to add another repeat inside the clicked element. This for create a little filme manager, so on folder click I want to add a list of file(

```
<li class="item_grid" ng-repeat="(id,f) in files | filter:query"  id="{{f.id}}" file-directive-right>
<div class="title" ng-click="clicked(id)">{{f.id}} - {{f.titolo}}</div>
</li>
```

this is my code the problem is add a repeat onclick, which is the best way?

Comment: You already have an `ng-click` inside the repeat?

Comment: yes, the problem is only insert another repeat on click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to design this with a directive and add DOM elements dynamically, but you *could* also do this with just "recursive" `ng-include` - I'll let others comment on whether this is a best practice or an anti-pattern :)

Basically, this leverages the child scope that `ng-repeat` creates for each child and `ng-init` to re-alias the name of the list (of folders, for example):

Let's say, the basic structure of folder contents is like so:

```
<ul>
  contents of: {{folder.name}}
  <li ng-repeat="f in folder.contents">

    <span ng-click="getFolderContents(f)">{{f.name}}</span>

    <ul ng-if="f.contents.length">
       contents of: {{f.name}}
       <li ng-repeat="childF in f.contents">
         ... etc
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can see the recursive nature. So, if we could abstract the inner folder into an `ng-include`, then we could reuse it.

The final solution would look like so:

```
<div ng-controller="folderCtrl">

    <ul ng-include="'folderTemplate'"></ul>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="folderTemplate">
       contents of: {{folder.name}}
       <li ng-repeat="f in folder.contents" ng-init="folder = f">

          <span ng-click="getFolderContents(f)">{{f.name}}</span>

          <ul ng-include="'folderTemplate'" ng-if="f.contents.length"></ul>
       </li>

    </script>  
</div>
```

Notice the `ng-init="folder = f"`. It sets the alias variable `folder` for each child scope. It is also, not incidentally, the same variable used by its parent, and ultimately, the root:

```
$scope.folder = {name: "folder 1", contents: []};
```

`getFolderContents` is just a function that populates `folder.contents` for a clicked-on folder.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ttyxIqD7Z3saFooCBftG?p=preview) to play with

Comment: thank u very much! I play a bit with this code and I solve the problem!